# Trim the object key using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, lodash

I want to trim the occurrences of object key y_ and get output like `useroutput`:

```
var user =[{"data":"2","y_data1":1},{"data":"4","y_data1":3,"y_data2":3}]
```

```
var useroutput=[{"data":"2","data1":1},{"data":"4","data1":3,"data2":3}]
```

Let me know of any approaches using lodash or javascript.

Comment: any approach using javascript is also fine.Tried using map but i have stuck

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**lodash#map**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map) to transform each item in the `user` array and [**lodash#mapKeys**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mapKeys) to transorm each of the `user` item's keys.

```
const result = _.map(user, data => 
  _.mapKeys(data, (v, k) => k.replace(/^y_/, '')));
```

```js
const user = [
  {"data":"2","y_data1":1},
  {"data":"4","y_data1":3,"y_data2":3}
];

const result = _.map(user, data => 
  _.mapKeys(data, (v, k) => k.replace(/^y_/, '')));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Pure JS solution: Use [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the item transformation, and a combination of [**Object.entries()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [**Array#reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve the key transformation.

```
const result = user.map(data =>
  Object.entries(data).reduce(
    (r, [k, v]) => (r[k.replace(/^y_/, '')] = v, r),
    {}
  )
);
```

```js
const user = [
  {"data":"2","y_data1":1},
  {"data":"4","y_data1":3,"y_data2":3}
];

const result = user.map(data =>
  Object.entries(data).reduce(
    (r, [k, v]) => (r[k.replace(/^y_/, '')] = v, r),
    {}
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without lodash using `array.map`, `array.reduce` and a regex to match your target key as follows:

```js
var user = [{"data":"2","y_1":1},{"data":"4","y_1":3,"y_2":3}]; 

console.log(user.map(o => 
  Object.keys(o).reduce((a, e) => {
    a[e.replace(/^y_/, "")] = o[e];
    return a;
  },
{})));
```

Comment: i used above method but I am seeing a discrepency in order here internally javscript is doing sorting when it end up in integer key                                                                                                            var user = [{"data":"2","y_1":1},{"data":"4","y_1":3,"y_2":3}];                            var useroutput = [{"1":1,"data":"2"},{"1":3,"2":3,"data":"4"}];  how we can avoid this

Comment: I wouldn't count on object keys to be in [any particular order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order). I'll look into a way to preserve it though.